# Cannot resolve org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I have a very simple Scala test project that provides the following error when I execute MyTestFileReader.scala:

> Error:scalac: Error:
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException Error
>   compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface-2.10.0-52.0'  at
>   sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:145)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
>     at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:291)     at
>   sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
>     at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:291)     at
>   sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$.compileSources(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
>     at sbt.compiler.IC$.compileInterfaceJar(IncrementalCompiler.scala:52)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$.org$jetbrains$jps$incremental$scala$local$CompilerFactoryImpl$$getOrCompileInterfaceJar(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:87)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$getScalac$1.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:44)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$getScalac$1.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:43)
>     at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)   at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.getScalac(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:43)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.createCompiler(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:22)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:24)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:24)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache$$anonfun$getOrUpdate$2.apply(Cache.scala:20)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.getOrUpdate(Cache.scala:19)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.createCompiler(CachingFactory.scala:23)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:22)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:67)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:24)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**MyTestFileReader.scala**

```
import java.util

object MyTestFileReader {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("src/main/resources/doc/test.json")

    System.out.println(lines)

  }

}
```

I am using IntelliJIDEA with Java 1.8 and Scala SDK 2.10.0. I tried to change Scala version in my POM.XML, but still the same issue:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Also, I tried to delete this dependency from POM. Nothing helps. The Scala plugin of IntellijIDEA is 3.0.6.